# Add real time data to chart control graph and switch between 2 graphs via combobox

Tags: c#, charts

I have application that received real time data and show this data on my chart control graph with timer:

```
MyObject obj = null;
Series seriesTraffic = null:

private void LoadGraph()
{
    seriesTraffic = new Series();
    seriesTraffic.Color = Color.Blue;
    seriesTraffic.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    seriesTraffic.BorderWidth = 2;
    chart1.Series.Add(seriesTraffic);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
}

private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var timer = (System.Windows.Forms.Timer)sender;
        MyObject wf2 = (MyObject)timer.Tag;
lblChartMbitSec.Text = string.Format("{0} Mbit/sec", (wf2.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001).ToString("0.##"));

    if (seriesTraffic.Points.Count() > 150)
        seriesTraffic.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    seriesTraffic.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

My object contain 2 `properties` that i want my graph to show seperate:

1. obj.BitsPerSecond
2. obj.PacketsPerSecond

Tnis is my `Combobox SelectedIndexChanged event`:

```
private void cbStatistics_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (cbStatistics.SelectedIndex == 0)
            timerChart.Tag = wf;
        else if (cbStatistics.SelectedIndex == 1)
            timerChart.Tag = wf;
}
```

When this selected index changed fired up i want to show my other graph, how can i do that ?

Comment: What have you already tried? Update the OP with some more information about what you tried, what worked, what didn't work, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two series objects, and update both of them at each timer tick - one for the bits per second, one for the packets per second:

```
private void LoadGraph()
{
    seriesBps = new Series("bps");
    seriesBps.Color = Color.Blue;
    seriesBps.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    seriesBps.BorderWidth = 2;
    chart1.Series.Add(seriesBps);

    seriesPps = new Series("pps");
    seriesPps.Color = Color.Blue;
    seriesPps.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    seriesPps.BorderWidth = 2;
    chart1.Series.Add(seriesPps);
    // set up axes as you already do
}
```

and then in your timer tick handler:

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (seriesBps.Points.Count() > 150)
        seriesBps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    seriesBps.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
    if (seriesPps.Points.Count() > 150) seriesPps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    seriesPps.Points.Add(wf.PacketsPerSecond);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

And, in your combo box event handler, enable the series you need:

```
private void cbStatistics_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbStatistics.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        seriesBps.Enabled = true;
        seriesPps.Enabled = false;
        lblChartMbitSec.Text = string.Format("{0} Mbit/sec", (wf2.BitsPerSecond *          0.000001).ToString("0.##")); // and similarly for the other case below
    }
    else if (cbStatistics.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        seriesBps.Enabled = false;
        seriesPps.Enabled = true;
    }
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();

}
```

Set the enabled flag on the two series in the `LoadGraph()` method to correspond to the initial state of the combo box.